# How to run sql query for each row value using set based approach

Tags: sql-server

I have following code placed inside a cursor and have to remove cursor due to performance issue. I am trying to use set based approach, with this I have to replace `@OriginalValue` and `@Per_Month` variable with SQL query as per set based approach but at the same time I need to perform below calculation each row (with value of `@OriginalValue` and `@Per_Month`)

If I am replacing `@OriginalValue` and `@Per_Month` with SQL query `SELECT OriginalValue and Per_Month FROM tblreport where reportDate = GETDATE()`", in this case below mention code is not yielding result in a row manner.

Eg. the cursor is declared for below records:

```
    OriginalValue  Per_Month
    ------------------------
    100            1
    200            3
    600            4
    500            7
```

Code:

```
set @Total =  (@Total * power(1 + (@Value1 / 100.0), @OriginalValue) + (@Per_Month / 100.0) * ( CASE WHEN @OriginalValue = 0 THEN 1 
ELSE
   CASE
      WHEN (@Value1 / 100.0)<> 0
        THEN (power(1 + (@Value1 / 100.0), @OriginalValue) - 1) / (@Value1 / 100.0) * (1 + (@Value1 / 100.0) * @Method)
      ELSE @OriginalValue 
   END
END))
```

Is there anyway I can perform the row based calculation using set based approach?

Comment: what are `@Value1`, `@Method`? are those fixed values or also coming from table? Also share you output with current data so that we can test our solution.

Comment: Actually cursor works better then set operation if no sub-query involved. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals

Comment: Good question! (upvote). It's a good idea to move from cursor/loop to a set-oriented approach.

Comment: @eric He is calculating a kind of running sum here. A cursor solution is *for sure* much much slower than a proper set-oriented approach.

Comment: @SQLPolice Well, it may help to get the big picture and to see the rest of the code. Is the `@Total` variable the single output? If we can see the rest of the code maybe we can integrate the cursor's logic directly into his main query, along with the calculation of the `@OriginalValue` and `@Per_month` and make it a set-based operation. Also, we need to know what `@value1` and `@method` come from. So, rather than just pasting in little bits of information at a time, I would post the entire part of the relevant code.

Comment: Given your example input, what do you expect to get back afterwards? Can you provide also the values for `@value1` and `@method`? I'll provide you a set based solution afterwards.

Comment: Too bad the calculation is  `Total * power + calculation`. If it was `Total * (power + calculation)` it would be relatively simple by using the Exp(log(sum(pow+calc))) approach for running products. There isn't any chance that it should be `set @total = @total * (power ... + ... end)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CTE to get the running total of the column. Assume @Value1, @Method is a static int

```
declare @Value1 int = 0, @Method int = 1

declare @Data table (Id int identity(1,1), OriginalValue int, Per_Month int)
insert @Data values (100, 1), (200, 3), (600, 4), (500, 7)

;with base as
(
    -- Your original logic
    select 
        *, 
        power(1 + (@Value1 / 100.0), OriginalValue) + (Per_Month / 100.0) 
        * 
        ( 
            CASE 
                WHEN OriginalValue = 0 THEN 1 
                ELSE 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN (@Value1 / 100.0)<> 0 THEN (power(1 + (@Value1 / 100.0), OriginalValue) - 1) / (@Value1 / 100.0) * (1 + (@Value1 / 100.0) * @Method) 
                        ELSE OriginalValue 
                    END 
            END
        ) CalLogic
    from @Data
),
runningTotal as
(
    select *, CalLogic AS Total from base where Id = 1
    union all
    select nxt.*, curr.Total * nxt.CalLogic from runningTotal curr inner join base nxt on curr.Id + 1 = nxt.Id
)
select * from runningTotal
```

Comment: Thanks @Eric and all friends for quirk response, for quick response, values of variables are Value1 =1.875  , Method = 1. And Total is a single output variable which is a running sum. The problem is to fetch OriginalValue and Per_month per row using set based.

Comment: Thank you @Eric, the above approach has solved my problem :)